# How to solve this setInterval issue?

Tags: javascript, geometry

I'm having trouble with setInterval. In my game I want the player to be able to shoot an arrow, but every time he shoots the arrows are going faster!
This is the arrow constructor:

```
arrows = [];

Arrow = function(x, y, followX, followY) // (player.x, player.y, followX, followY)
{
     ar = this;

     ar.rect = [x, y, 28, 3];

     ar.x = x;
     ar.y = y;

     ar.followX = followX;
     ar.followY = followY;

     if(ar.followY - ar.y < 0)
     {
          ar.where = [-(((ar.followX - ar.x)/200)/((ar.followY - ar.y)/200)), -1];
     }
     else
     {
          ar.where = [(((ar.followX - ar.x)/200)/((ar.followY - ar.y)/200)), 1];
     }

     ar.flying = setInterval(function()
     {
          ar.rect[0] += ar.where[0]/10;
          ar.rect[1] += ar.where[1]/10;
     }, 1);

     ar.fall = setTimeout(function()
     {
          for(a = 0; a < arrows.length; a++)
               if (arrows[a] == ar)
               {
                    clearInterval(ar.flying);
                    arrows = sliceHere(arrows, a);
               }
     }, 1000);
}
```

So the general idea is that the arrow flies for one second, and then gets deleted.

This is how and arrow gets created:

```
fireArrow = function(player)
{
     arrows.push(new Arrow(player.rect[0] + player.rect[2] - 1, player.rect[1] + player.rect[3]/2 - 10, player.rect[0] + player.mouse.x - sx/2, player.rect[1] + player.mouse.y - sy/2));
}
```

After that, I'm just drawing arrows on the screen, I also always fire from the same spot, and in the same direction.

Comment: Do you really want 1 millisecond in setInterval?

Comment: @erturne - good point. I forgot to mention that in my answer, but yes, the browser isn't really going to give you a 1ms interval even if it's not busy doing other things.

Comment: I know, but this runs using Node ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem, but you should change this line:

```
ar = this;
```

to

```
var ar = this;
```

And the same for your `a` loop counter.

At the moment you don't use `var` anywhere which means *all* of your variables are global.

Which in general is going to lead to all kinds of confusion, but more specifically means that if you fire multiple arrows, each will kick off its own `setInterval` but the references to `ar` in the interval function will all refer to the same global variable and so will all move the most recently fired arrow thus making it speed up.

Declare `ar` with `var` and it becomes local to the `Arrow` function (but is still accessible to functions nested inside that function like the ones you create for your `setInterval`). The magic of closures means each of your intervals will refer only to the now local `ar` from the surrounding scope and each arrow will become properly independent.

The only time you should ever use a variable without declaring it with `var` is when you specifically *want* to create a global from within a function. And even then you should ask yourself if that's the best way to go.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the use of globals. They have a performance penalty too, because the scope chain has to be walked to resolve them.